# Sprite jitter on movement with pixel perfect camera and Cinemachine in Unity

Tags: unity, rigidbody, cinemachine

I have been struggling to get rid of jittery sprites in my game. I've been pulling my hair out for past 4 weeks trying to fix this issue. So I cooked up a small show case project with my player that can only move left and right.
I'm using a state machine to handle my player and only states that I included in this project is idle and move state. I'm also using cinemachine and pixel perfect camera and my jitter appears only when my player starts moving.
I'd appreciate if someone could take a look at it.

here is link to the project zip file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qxWdmzwIZkBmukhy4x7aFuZgkVYEOB7E/view?usp=sharing

Also if you need any more info about anything let me know.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Directly posting code that shows a small example of the problem & some sample output is preferred over linking to your project. First, it makes it easier for others to look for the problem, which in turn makes it more likely that you'll get an answer. Second, links go dead over time - the idea behind GDSE is not just to solve your problem, but to provide help to others with similar problems. That works much better if your question is self contained & doesn't required downloading your full project.

Comment: I already tried posting my code and detailed problem on stackoverflow and we came to conclusion that it would be easier to post a small project that shows the problem.

here is the link to stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070163/sprite-jitter-on-movement-with-pixel-perfect-camera-and-cinemachine-in-unity

Comment: Based on the SO comment thread, it seems like the problem wasn't narrowed down sufficiently. That's one of the problems that can be avoided by making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is what I'm suggesting you include here.

Comment: so from what I can read the so called  minimal reproducible example is a fraction of the code that the problem can be reporduced with and I feel like I included everything that is needed to do that. Could you elaborate on whats unclear about the example I posted ?

Comment: I'm not making claims about clarity. The help describes good examples as being minimal, complete & reproducible. Complete is clarified as: "Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*" (emphasis theirs). Your code isn't in the question itself, it's somewhere else.

Comment: I solved this by placing all static objects on the positions that are on the "sprite grid". All the sprites are 16 pixels per unit and all are placed on positions that are 1/16 of the unit. Moving objects still move freely (i.e. their positions are not rounded to 1/16). This ensures that when the camera moves all the static pixel perfect sprites are "rounded"(i.e. moved relative to the camera) on the same frame.

Comment: Forgot to mention that in the sprite editor the pivot of all the sprites must be pixel perfect too. There is an option to position it rounded in relation to sprites' pixels.

Comment: @Nikaas thanks for your response, I still dont understand how would I round the positions of the sprites to the pixel grid maybe you could elaborate a little more on that, perhaps you could give me a code example?

Comment: If sprites are say 16PPU all objects are placed on positions that are 1/16 of a Unity distance unit. There is a package called ProGrids that rounds the placement positions to whatever value you select for rounding.

Comment: Or you can do it even manually but it's tidious, say type for X position in the inspector 43+5/16.